# How to combine multiple gz files into one from Process in C# program when one is missing EOF

Tags: c#, linux

I have multiple .gz files in a directory (2 or more), with at least one file missing the end of file marker.  Our C# process is unable to read the file with missing end of file, but since they are coming from a third party we do not have control over how they are created.

As such, we've been running the following Linux command manually:

`cat file1.gz file2.gz > newFile.gz`

In order to automate this, I am looking for a way to leverage the Process functionality in C# to trigger the same command, but this would only be available in Cygwin or some other Linux shell.  In my example, I'm using git bash but it could be Powershell or Cygwin or any other available Linux shell that runs on a Windows box.

The following code does not fail, but it does not work as expected.  I am wondering if anyone has recommendations about how to do this or any suggestions on a different approach to consider?

Assume that the working directory is set and initialized successfully, so the files exist where the process is run from.

```
Process bashProcess = new Process();
bashProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe";
bashProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

bashProcess.Start();

bashProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("cat file1.gz file2.gz > newFile.gz");
bashProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
bashProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
.
.
.
bashProcess.WaitForExit();
```

My expectation is that newFile.gz is created

Comment: Why would you want to it in this cumbersome way? Why not just use file I/O as provided by the .NET class libraries? Most decent tutorials/guides about file I/O in C#/.NET will give you sufficient insight into how you can do it (without relying on 3rd party program swhich you have run as separate process while trying to feed commands to them...)

Comment: @elgonzo I actually had tried to use I/O provided by .NET, but the missing end of file in the first gz file prevents the stream from opening and reading the file to append it to the second one.  It gets to the end of the first file, can't find the end of stream marker, and hangs. Believe me, I'd MUCH prefer to do what you're recommending. As I mentioned, I am not able to control the missing eof as it's coming from a third party system.

Comment: I am confused about why are you talking about "_end of file_" missing. What exactly are you referring to? Unless a file is of infinite size (which is impossible, obviously), a file will have an end. There is no marker for the end of a file. A file simply has an end, like it has a start. I also don't know why/how the problem of your program hanging would fit into that. Perhaps ask a new question, specifically showing and explaining the issue you had with .NET's I/O functions. Also don't forget to include a [mcve] that's representative of how exactly is/was your actual code using .NET I/O.

Comment: I have a gz file that, when we use the Reader that is approved, or when trying to open the file using 7zip (or similar programs), I am getting an error that says "Can not open file .... as archive."

We get a batch of files for processing in ETL, the first 1-2 files are like this and the last one we are able to open/decompress without any issues.

We've found that by concatenating the file set into one, we are able to work with it using our reader.

My question was around how to run a Linux command from CSharp, but I actually found a solution (below) using Windows copy command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem using a DOS command, and spawning a cmd Process from CSharp.

My code now looks like this, avoids having to launch a linux-based shell from Windows, and the copy command in windows does the same thing as cat:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C pushd \\server\folder && copy *.txt.gz /b 
    combined.gz";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

while (line != null)
{
    output.Append(line);
    line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```